# Formatting date in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, datetime, formatting

I would like my date to be YYYY-MM-DD (DD-MM-YYYY), I can't seem to convert into this form. I have already looked at [CAST and Convert T-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql).

As a general question can I format the date according to my need such as DD-MM (YEAR) etc. You can easily do that in MYSQL.

```
SELECT GETDATE() // start with this query
```

Comment: As a general answer, don't format in SQL, do the formatting in your front end, report writer, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the date without the time:

```
--char(10) limits the length to 10 characters thereby removing the time stamp
SELECT CONVERT(char(10), GetDate(),126) -- Output: 2011-11-07
```

To get the date with the time stamp:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, GetDate(), 126) --Output: 2011-11-07T13:42:25.913
```

See [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) for all possible formats.

Comment: And btw can I format it according to my needs like DD-MM(YYYY)

Comment: Now I get the logic of it, with varchar(10), the rest of the data is ignored. someone should have explained that :)

Answer (score 0):

Try format `120`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 120) -- result: 2011-11-07 13:48:45
```

If you want to truncate this so only the date part is returned, specify a size constraint on the `VARCHAR` conversion:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120) -- result: 2011-11-07
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), GETDATE(), 120) /*YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS(24h)*/

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), GETDATE(), 126) /*YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS:MMM*/

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 102) AS [YYYY.MM.DD]

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 111) AS [YYYY/MM/DD]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely NOT the fastest option, but it matches what you requested and may be useful to someone else in the future.

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME
SET @date = GETDATE()
SELECT CAST(DATEPART(YYYY, @date) AS NVARCHAR(4)) + '-' 
 + CAST(DATEPART(MM, @date) AS NVARCHAR(2)) + '-'
 + CAST(DATEPART(DD, @date) AS NVARCHAR(2)) + ' ('
 + CAST(DATEPART(DD, @date) AS NVARCHAR(2)) + '-'
 + CAST(DATEPART(MM, @date) AS NVARCHAR(2)) + '-'
 + CAST(DATEPART(YYYY, @date) AS NVARCHAR(4)) + ')'
```

It outputs:

```
2011-11-7 (7-11-2011)
```